# IE8 - Security Warning - Need to disabled this message forever

Tags: windows-xp, internet-explorer-8, security-warning

One of our HR coordinator is getting the Security Warning almost everytime she goes on our secured (HTTPS) corporate insurance website (And ADP) to fill out some information but every time she changes from a page to another one, she gets the message to click Yes or No.

Since I'm in a corporate IT environment, some of the settings can't be changed due to GPO. But let me show you what I've done:

- Tools / Internet Options / Security / Internet Zone / Custom… dialog, the “Display mixed content” option can be set to “Disable.” ([http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2009/06/22/9797918.aspx](https://web.archive.org/web/20120806015009/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/ieinternals/archive/2009/06/22/9797918.aspx))
- The sites are in the Trusted sites zone

So now I'm a bit confused why she gets these messages anyway. Our IT Security admin says that it should be coming from their end but I doubt it... GreatWest and ADP at the same time??? Really???

Any takers on this one?

Comment: XP?, have you tried updating the root certificates via windows updates>Software Optional...this is done automatically in Vista/W7, but not XP

Comment: You really really need to provide details as to what "Security Warning" is coming up.  There are many security issues to warn about, and resolving different issues requires different settings.  Provide exact text if possible.

Comment: Security Warning - Do you want to view only the webpage content that was delivered securely? - This webpage contains content that will not be delivered using a secure HTTPS connection, which could compromise the security of the entire webpage.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like their SSL certificate either isn't trusted by default, or isn't configured properly.

Try a different browser, if it still happens then it's most likely this.

Comment: Is that SSL certificate need to be installed/configured on the HR Coordinator or it must be pushed from the website?

Comment: Not sure. It can be a problem both ends - if it's only on this computer, I'd guess it's a problem there, if everyone gets it, then it's the server managers fault.